# How can I recover data from lg g4 stuck in a boot loop?

Tags: boot-loop, data-recovery, lg

My lg g4 is stuck in a boot loop. It still powers on and can charge up but my phone wont stay on for long before it shuts down and starts booting up again. I dont really care about saving the phone but i just want to get all my data from it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can connect your mobile to your computer via **ADB** (Android Debug Bridge) and easily copy all your stuff to your computer.To do this, just:

1. Boot into recovery mode by holding the Power & Volume Up buttons on your phone. (if Volume Up doesn't work, try Volume Down and if there are other hardware keys try them too).
2. Now connect your mobile to your PC using a USB.(You must have the usb driver installed on your pc). Download ADB from the internet and run command prompt or terminal.
3. Use the command **adb pull filepath+name destinationOnYourPC**.
4. Congratulations, if you were successfully.

> For more detailed information, prefer a quick search on the internet. Even if you are new to this, you can easily learn these all by watching tutorials on YouTube. But I hope you are familiar with all this. By the way, what stuck your phone in bootloop.